# GitHub sign in page when cloning a repo using git bash

Tags: git, github, clone, git-clone

In my company, we sign-in to GitHub by entering username as userID_compnaydomain. And then the password field is disabled and 'Sign in' button is changed to 'Sign in with organization'. When we try to clone a repo using git bash, I get the below popup and we sign in with the browser.

[image]

But for one user, instead of above popup, they received below popup. We won't be able to login if we give our company email and password. On what basis, this popup is shown? Is there any setting that makes the git bash to show specific popup?

[image]

Comment: Those two pop ups look the same to me. Did you paste the wrong screen capture in one of the two cases?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Uploaded incorrect image.

Comment: You could check the configuration of the user compared to others regarding they keys mentioned on that page: https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

Answer (score 0):

Git itself doesn't "do" authentication.<sup>1</sup>  Instead, when some Git hosting service requires authentication of some sort before the hosting service will serve you, Git farms that authentication out to some other program.

There are two main ways to do this:

- Git can use `ssh`, the [Secure Shell system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh).  Although the details here get quite involved, Git itself stays completely hands-off: it literally just *runs* `ssh`, and ssh takes care of everything from that point on.

  You use this system when your URL starts with `ssh://`.  There's a funky `user@host:path/to/repo.git` URL syntax specific to Git that Git internally translates into `ssh://user@host/path/to/repo.git` so that it can invoke `ssh`; some people prefer this syntax since it's slightly shorter, but I prefer the longer syntax since it's clearer.
- Git can use HTTPS and its authentication system.  This is itself inherently far more complicated than ssh, as the https authentication systems themselves vary, so Git shoves the authentication part off into what Git calls *credential helpers*.

  You use this system when your URL starts with `https://`.

We can see, from a fragment included in one screenshot, that you're using `https://` URLs here.  So you are invoking a credential helper.  To use GitHub, you'll want one of the (many) credential helpers that speaks the protocols GitHub define.

If everything is working well for most users, but not for one particular user, it's likely that that one particular user has configured his or her Git to use a *different* credential helper by default, and the one he or she chose is not cooperating with GitHub.

As [max630 noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74383443/github-sign-in-page-when-cloning-a-repo-using-git-bash#comment131334840_74383443), you probably want the [Git Credential Manager helper](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md) here.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git has some very limited internal support for authentication, but only enough to farm it out to the other programs as shown above.